# PHP - Automatically Submitting/Running A Form

Tags: php, forms, submit

I recently posted a question about php forms with a checkbox that simply echoed the result and it was answered.

However i now have the question how can i automatically submit the form so rather than waiting for the submit button to be clicked once it would automatically echo the result.

I would like a way to run the form once because i wanted to make far more complex forms and would like to display the initial result right away.

The other thread:

[PHP - Form Elements Resetting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29525885/php-form-elements-resetting)

Many thanks

Comment: Not sure I understand. Isn't it up to the user to press submit? How can you tell they are finished filling the form? Even all fields completed doesn't man they will pop back and change something.

Comment: Well say i had 3 checkboxes and the first 2 of them were set to on as default and the last off i want it to load the page and echo true, true, false. Then if they ticked the last and pressed submit it would just update, basically i just want an initial load for the output. The only way i know how to do this right now is by duplicating all of the code, placing it outside of the submit if code and slightly modifying it. I thought perhaps there is a nicer way than duplicating lots of code like a form_run() type command from php etc.

Comment: After the page has been loaded the server is finished executing php until the next request. Your php code does not continue running as the form is being used. The best way to trigger events when the user clicks a checkbox is to use javascript.

Comment: I guess i could use .click in js but i was hoping for a pure php way to run the form, kind of like auto clicking submit. I have my workaround of the extra duplicate code which i guess is the only way.